# Magento 2: Impossible open catalog --> products

Tags: magento2

We have about 110k products. Currently during open admin catalog products in backend I get every time timout.

For test I disable timeout in .htaccess

```
    RewriteRule .* - [E=noabort:1]
RewriteRule .* - [E=noconntimeout:1]
```

Now I can open catalog products, but this take about 6 minutes. Is very long.

Does anyone have any solution how this can be accelerated?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you still have an issue with server configuration.

Try the below solution that might helpful for you

it was ensuring the nginx and php-fpm did not timeout. Ensure to add:

fastcgi_read_timeout 600;
proxy_read_timeout 600;

Also refer this link - https://asdqwe.net/blog/solutions-504-gateway-timeout-nginx/